# Можно ли как то подключить проект к базе данных доступ к которой можно получить через ssh тунель

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh

Есть сервер, чтобы получить доступ к его базе нужно подключаться по ssh. Можно ли как то подключить локальный проект к базе с ssh  подключением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно пробросить порт через ssh на локальную машину:

```
ssh example.com -L 3306:127.1:3306
```